# Decimal data is rounding up or down once it is populated from stage to reporting table

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, sqldatatypes

I have an SSIS job in Sql server where four different fields in the stage table are set to Data type decimal(18,2). The data in those fields in the stage table are correct because I am expecting non-zero values to the right of the decimal `Example  200.56`. But when the package runs the population from stage to reporting all of the values to the right of the decimal are 00, so I assume the insertion is rounding up or down `Example: 201.00` . However, the 4 fields in the stage table are being populated to fields in the reporting table that have the same data type decimal(18,2). I have tried dropping the reporting table and recreating it with another name. When I do a preview of the data in Visual Studio it gives me a sample   with the correct format and values to the right of the decimal >0. The query is a simple select statement without any transformation. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Try to create minimal repro.  Are you performing any calculations on the values in TSQL or SSIS?

Comment: I have been altering the pipeline to see if I can get different results, but no there are no calculations or transformations on those fields or any other fields.

Comment: How are you moving data from 'stage table' to 'reporting table'? do you use just SQL 'insert into reportingtable ... select ... from stage`, or an SSIS data-flow task? If the latter, review the metadata on the link between the source and the destination components.

Comment: I am using SSIS data flow package. It looks like I was able to resolve the problem by using ISNULL returning 00.00 when populating data from Stage to Reporting table. Which doesn't really make sense since the same figures populated with nulls just fine from upstream